# How do you manually block-quote in Gmail's new compose interface?

Tags: gmail, formatting

Gmail recently released a [new UI for compose](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/introducing-new-compose-in-gmail.html). How do you manually quote a paragraph? The block-quote button seems to have disappeared from the formatting toolbar in the rich text compose editor.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The quote button is inside the **More formatting options** menu on the formatting toolbar. When you click the arrow, a submenu pops up with a few more options, depending on the width of your window.

[image: Screenshot of compose with quote button]

Comment: "No offense Google, but why did you hide that Quote function to align on that new compose UI?! There are enough place in that line..." - I sent them that suggestion, you may do so here: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=suggestions.cs&rd=1

Comment: not available if you compose emails in plain text mode.

Comment: Wow, I would have never found it.

Comment: Just keep using the old compose: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50178/18147

Comment: The interface seems to have been updated, as of the writing of this comment, to put the indentation buttons at the top level.

Comment: @PatrickSanan, I updated the screenshot.

Comment: Is there anyway to access these formatting options from the gmail app?

Answer (score 16):

To quote, you can also select the text and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> on OS X.

This shortcut works only in rich text mode.

Comment: This is not available if you compose emails in 'plain text' (which is actually recommended... quite frustrating)