# Is there any way to get back the old style Gmail reply and compose boxes?

Tags: gmail, user-interface

Is there any way besides using a 3rd party email application to revert Gmail to the old-style compose and reply email boxes - the style that allows you to use your full screen?

It drives me absolutely insane when a company makes an 'enhancement' and reduces usable window space.  If I am writing a long email I want to be able to use the maximum amount of window space and not be crammed into something that is 25% of my monitor size.

[image: Compose window example]

Comment: If you shift-click the compose button, the compose will open in a separate browser, which you can then maximize.

Comment: There is a new extension in the Chrome Web store called [Retro Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk) that lets you toggle between the new and old versions

Comment: There exist 3 Google Chrome and Firefox extensions: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50178/18147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid Google has made the change permanent. As per the [FAQ](http://learn.googleapps.com/new-gmail-compose/new-compose-faq), the previous experience will go away eventually. It was inevitable.

Although you can still use the old style compose on IE 8, because it does not support the newer  Gmail interface. Maybe one can trick it to behave like IE 8 on other browsers too.

You don't have to change browsers, just tell ie9 or ie10 to pretend to be ie8.  To do this press f12 to get the developer tools.  Then chose both "Browser Mode: IE8" and "Document Mode: IE8 standards"

Comment: In going to use [eM Client desktop client](http://www.emclient.com/) on my windows boxes as a replacement

Comment: Please remove this answer as the information is now deprecated as there exist three Google Chrome and Firefox extensions: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50178/18147