# Returning to an earlier version of Gmail

Tags: gmail

Does anyone know how to revert to earlier forms of Gmail?

Failing that, how do I make the reply or forward take up the full screen and not be a window on top of a window as in the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked in a different format already. See

[How do I opt-out of the new Reply in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/how-do-i-opt-out-of-the-new-reply-in-gmail)

One answer suggests that the basic HTML view of old Gmail can be accessed using this URI:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/27pbkbpwk5yx/?f=1