# How can I restore the Google link bar that used to be on top of my Gmail web interface?

Tags: google-toolbar

I used to have a handy link bar on top of my Gmail web interface:

[image]

Now it's gone:

[image]

How can I have the link bar back? I don't want to have to do an extra click on the app icon on the top right.

Answer (score 6):

It's the latest design change of Google. You can still access the options by clicking that new icon beside the notification bell. [From the support](https://support.google.com/toolbar/answer/1247010?hl=en) -

> You may have noticed that some or all of your Toolbar buttons have
>   disappeared with the latest update of Toolbar. The newest version of
>   Toolbar helps you focus on the features you use the most, by removing
>   your less frequently used buttons from view.
>
> If you’ve recently used a specific Tool on your Toolbar, its button
>   will be pinned to the Toolbar so that you have easy access to it.
>   Otherwise, all buttons are removed by default.
>
> Don’t fret -- you can easily add your favorite features back to the
>   Toolbar. Click More next to the search box and select the tool that
>   you want to add. It’ll automatically appear back on the Toolbar. If
>   you don’t see the feature in the More menu, make sure it’s enabled in
>   the Options dialog.

There is no way to bring it back. (Unless you write your own HTML and CSS and inject it to every single Google page.)

Comment: Thanks, then I'll be waiting for some browser extensions to fix Google designer mess just like I did for getting rid of the new Gmail compose (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50178/18147): as indicated in the question, I don't want to have to do an extra click on the app icon on the top right.