# Can I view attachments as HTML in the new Gmail interface?

Tags: gmail

Gmail has recently changed the [UI for attachments](http://googlesystem.blogspot.sk/2013/11/gmail-new-attachment-ui-powered-by-google-drive.html). The options offered for an attachment is to download it to disk, save it to Google Drive or right click to open it in a new tab.

In the old interface I quite often used the *view* option when the attachment was a PDF or DOC file or something similar. I found the option *[view as HTML](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et070306.htm)* in the built-in viewer quite useful, in particular when I wanted to copy some part of text from the attachment.

Can I somehow view the attachment *as HTML* in the new interface?

I mean something like the [plain HTML mode](http://www.wondershare.com/pdf/tips-for-viewing-and-managing-pdf-in-gmail.html)—see the following picture:

[image: gmail-pdf-html.jpg]

Comment: FYI: [Revert to the old Gmail interface](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50178/18147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Click anywhere else but on the *Download* or *Save to Drive* buttons and it will open the document inline, in an overlay.

[image]

Like this:

[image]

And here you can see that the document is rendered as HTML:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this. I do not see how to get to *view as html* option.

Comment: @Martin That _is_ the HTML view. If you open a document, be it PDF or DOC, like that and then check it with the web inspector, you will see that its content is rendered as HTML.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that I can copy the text even from this view. (I am not sure whether I remember it correctly, but I think I had to choose plain HTML if I wanted to copy text in the old interface.)

Comment: You most certainly _can_ copy text from this view, either from a PDF or from a DOC. (I personally like better this view that the previous open-in-new-tab one.)